# Python: how to detect slider movement and call a function without sending any arguments over?

Tags: python, function, slider, signals, pyqt4

Is there a way to detect slider movement and call another function without sending any arguments with the signal?

I have a function that has default argument installed in it so it's needless to say that if I call it using a signal that has an argument with it (slider.valueChanged()) it overwrites the default argument.

```
      funcdic = {}
      for x in range(0,3):
        def slidechanged(foo=x):
            svalue = str(self.sliderdic1[foo].value())
            self.entrydic2[foo].setText(svalue)
            print svalue
        funcdic.update({x:slidechanged})
```

Comment: What slider?  Are you using some GUI library?  If so, which one?

Comment: I'm using pyqt4, sorry for not mentioning it eariler

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, calling the function without passing arguments is easily done using lambda, my bad for forgetting such a simple thing. I have three sliders in a dictionary so I made three signals.

```
      funcdic = {}
      for x in range(0,3):
        def slidechanged(foo=x):
            print foo
            svalue = str(self.sliderdic1[foo].value())
            self.entrydic2[foo].setText(svalue)
            print svalue
        funcdic.update({x:slidechanged})

      self.sliderdic1[0].valueChanged.connect(lambda: funcdic[0]())
      self.sliderdic1[1].valueChanged.connect(lambda: funcdic[1]())
      self.sliderdic1[2].valueChanged.connect(lambda: funcdic[2]())
```